# Чи можна Олександра кликати Лесиком?

Tags: власні-назви

Мого хресного звуть Олександр, однак всі кличуть його Лесик. Однак, на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9_(%D1%96%D0%BC%27%D1%8F)) знайшов інформацію, що Лесик - це скорочення від імені Олексій. Однак, на цьому [форумі](http://posydenky.lvivport.com/threads/vibirajemo-imja-dlja-ditinki-2.102973/page-97) я також знайшов інформацію,  що Олександрів називають Лесиками:

> Саша - це швидше російський варіант скорочення імен
>   Олександр/Олександра. Маю знайомого дорослого Олександра, якого
>   називають Олесем. А ще досить популярне скорочення імені Олександр -
>   Лесик. Недавно спілкувалася з батьками маленького хлопчика Олександра,
>   батьки якого взагалі проти того, щоб якось скорочувати ім'я сина.
>   Лагідно називають його Олександриком.

Отож, чи можливе таке скорочення цього імені, а якщо ні, то чому деякі люди його використовують?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Із [3-го видання словника-довідника Л. Г. Скрипник і Н. П. Дзятківської «Власні імена людей» за редакцією В. М. Русанівського (Київ, «Наукова думка», 2005), с. 84](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Skrypnyk_Larysa/Vlasni_imena_liudei_Slovnyk-dovidnyk/) (також із помилками розпізнавання на [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/54/53406/363496.html))

> Олекса́ндр (Оле́сь, Лесь) *гр.*; аlехō — захищаю і anēr (*род.* andros) —
>   чоловік (буквально: мужній оборонець; захисник людей). Оле́сько,
>   Оле́сик, Оле́лько; ***Ле́сько, Ле́сик***, Лесю́та, Лель; Са́ня, Санько́, Сашко́,
>   Са́ша, Сашу́ля, Сашу́ня; Шу́ра, Шурко́; А́лик.

Із статті Вікіпедії ["Олександр"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80)

> В українській мові, завдяки властивій їй особливості, початковий звук
>   А- пом'якшувався О- або ж взагалі відкидався, а також додавався
>   зменшувально-пестливий суфікс, зокрема `-сь` з утворенням імен **Олесь та
>   Лесь.** Однак, поступово пестлива форма увійшла в мову, втративши своє
>   «пестливе» значення, та стала побутовою. Нині зазначенні імена на ряду
>   з Олександром вважаються офіційними документальними українськими
>   іменами.
>
> Грубувато-фамільярне або дружнє вживання імені — <…> ***Олесик, Лесик*** <…>.

Тому, відповідь на Ваше питання — так, таке скорочення можливе.

Comment: Добра відповідь, а _Лисик_, схоже, далебі з _Лесик_, бо, мені здајетьсьа, наголошенньа на другиј склад, а отже ненаголошене _е_ стало _и_, тобто подібна зміна, јак і з зајменником <її>.

Comment: @follower, _Ле́сик_ — наголос на перший склад. В цитаті були помилки розпізнавання скану (я виправив).